# Difference between "Staging" and "Production" endpoint slot in LUIS

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I didn't find any documentation explaining the difference between "Staging" and "Production" endpoint slot. I think, that staging means the same as debugging mode, but I'm not sure. It would be great to hear an explanation from you.

Kind regards,
Kamil

Answer (score 2):

It will work as just any other Staging/Production deployment slot.

The **Production Slot** should contain the stable version of your app that will be used by your end users

The **Staging Slot** is aimed to have a safe environment to test new thing you are adding to your LUIS app, without breaking the Production Slot (which is being consumed by users). Once the testing of the staging version pass your test criteria, you can promote/deploy to Production.

Take a look at the [Publish your App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/publishapp) documentation article for more information.